# Pass multiline parameter to powershell script

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have a TeamCity build with prompt text parameter, and I pass it into powershell script (by using PowerShell runner, with script file and execution mode "Execute .ps1 from external file"). Script argument looks like below:

```
-MyParameter1 "%myparameter1%"
-MyParameter2 "%myparameter2%"
```

Build initiating user can enter multiline parameter. Example below:

```
multiline test
second line
3rd line
```

And in this case I am getting an error:

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'test
>   second line 3rd line'.

In the TeamCity log I am seeing next command:

```
Command: C:\Windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
PowerShell arguments: -NoProfile, -NonInteractive, -ExecutionPolicy, ByPass, -File, C:\BuildAgent\work\***\MyScript.ps1, -MyParameter1, "1578", -MyParameter2, "multiline test, second, line, 3rd, line"
```

Parameter definition in Script.ps1:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[String]$MyParameter2,
```

TeamCity version: 2018.1.1

What can I do to pass multiline parameter to powershell script?

Comment: You are sending a single string `"multiline test, second, line, 3rd, line"` as the second parameter to the ps1 script you are not showing us. My guess is you should make that parameter accept an array of strings `[string[]]` and send the multiple lines also as array (not as a strangely comma delimited string)

Comment: @Theo parameter has type `String`, I tried `String[]` but nothing changed

Comment: @Theo the problem is I am not formatting multiline parameter with commas. This is TeamCity. I am passing it as usual

Comment: @Zergatul did you ever solve this? I'm also getting commas in my multiline parameter passed to Powershell on TC.

Comment: @JulianHanssen no, I use solution I provided in answer

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution. Before executing necessary PowerShell script, add step with inline PowerShell in TeamCity:

```
$param2 = @'
%myparameter2%
'@
$param2 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($param2)
$param2 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($param2)
Write-Output "##teamcity[setParameter name='myparameter2' value='$param2']"
```

This script will replace build parameter `myparameter2` with its base64 representation. You can pass it as usual parameter to script, and then do base64 decode.